# Microsoft Translator - Check usage?

Tags: translate

I just signed up for Microsoft Translate. I've done a bit of searching online, but I want to know if it is possible to check my usage with this service. I don't want to go over the 2 million character limit and end up getting billed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To track usage do the following:

Go to [My Data page on Azure Marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/account/datasets)

You'll see your Microsoft Translator subscription with the number of remaining characters you have left.

If you go over your quota you won't get billed, it will just stop translating your requests and give you an error message.

[Link to MS Translator FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/c71aeddd-cc90-4228-93cc-51fb969fde09)

Have a look at question 21.  That should re-assure you you won't get billed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I don't know system of microsoft translator in use.But if it isn't `gettext`, install `gtranslator` and use `gettext`.